# Tomcat7 Manager GUI 401

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, http-status-code-401, tomcat-manager

When I try to access my home server from my laptop via domain.com/manager I get brought to the page that says "401 Unauthorized You are not authorized to view this page. If you have not changed any configuration files, please examine the file conf/tomcat-users.xml in your installation. That file must contain the credentials to let you use this webapp....". However, when I try to go the manager gui from the desktop computer that is hosting tomcat, it gives me the option to log in and everything works fine.

I have set up tomcat-users.xml to look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="user" password="pass" roles='admin-gui,manager-gui'/>
</tomcat-users>
```

and I have made sure to force-reload and restart.... what am I missing?